# Create JSON batch output from pyspark to HDFS

Tags: python, json, pyspark, hive, hdfs

I am converting some hive tabular data into JSON documents using pyspark and writing output to HDFS for downstream consumption. code snippt looks like this:

```
def convertToJson(x):
    data = ....... #transformation_code
    output = row(str(json.dumps(data))
    return output
df1 = spark.sql("""select * from json_ready_tbl""")
rdd1 = df.rdd.map(lambda x: convertToJson(x)).saveAsTextFile('/hdfs/output/dir')
```

The output JSON of convertToJSON function is nested but at a high level looks something like this:

```
{
  "id": 1001,
  "info": {
     "count": 12345,
     "code": 999
      }
}
```

So basically, the output files have a JSON string in each row. We then create a hive table on top of this text files by adding some metadata to each row like date and client_name for further downstream consumption as follows:

```
date         client_name  json_obj
2020-04-01   zeus         { "id": 1001, "info": { "count": 12345, "code": 999 } }
...
N number of rows
```

Now the challenge is, we have to batch these JSON files upto 1000 into an array of JSONs and write to HDFS  so the output in hive table should look like this:

```
date         client_name  json_batch
2020-04-01   zeus         [{obj1}, {obj2}, {obj3},...{obj1000}]
...
T number of rows
```

How can I achieve this? Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Please provide an example of the data you want to convert in it's original format. What you're asking is basically two things - first convert to json the data, then aggregate it in bulks of 1K elements?